# Has the Libyan Investment Authority had $150 Billion of overseas investments frozen?

Tags: libya

GlobalResearch.ca has an [article by Michel Chossudovsky](http://www.globalresearch.ca/destroying-a-country-s-standard-of-living-what-libya-had-achieved-what-has-been-destroyed/26686) that says the [Libyan Investment Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libyan_Investment_Authority) has had around $150 Billion of oversears investments frozen.

> Libya`s frozen overseas financial assets are estimated to be of the
> order of $150 billion, with **NATO countries holding more than $100
> billion.**
>
> Prior to the war, Libya had no debts. In fact quite the opposite. It
> was a creditor nation investing in neighboring African countries.

This image was taken from that article:

[image: Estimated Libyan Funds, Invested over]

> Estimated Libyan finds, invested overseas by the Libyam Investment Authority; $150 BILLION
>
> [...]
>
> Total Libyan funds held by the Invading NATO alliance $99.06 BILLION. Almost 2/3's of Libya's foreign investments.
>
> Just happen to be held in countries that form the NATO invading forces.